# How to copy Big files on other Linux Server Independent of TTY

Tags: rhel, scp

Actually i was trying to copy all the files in another director. Total size of the file is 188GB so its going to take a time.

Im trying to copy for Linux server A to B using this command

```
nohup scp Files-from-Server-A root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:tmp &
```

but as soon i close the terminal it stops copying the files but the process is still shown in process manager.

Comment: Allowing remote access from the root user is pretty bad practice btw. Hackers always try and login as root user with guessed passwords, so it's best to block remote access as root entirely.

Comment: Yes Alex, This is the test system on my own machine. So no worries.

Comment: What is the contents of `nohup.out` created by the `nohup` program?

Comment: Nothing its totally empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scp` does detect whether it's got a controlling tty. If you run it as a foreground process it will show a progress bar, but if you background it, the progress bar disappears, so there are some internal checks going on. I would do as @peterph says and start the transfer in either a `tmux` or `screen` session. I'm not sure of the implications of using `nohup`, but just keep a controlling terminal active.

As the file is that big, if it's not compressed, I'd also add compression to the transfer with `scp`'s `-C` option.

If it's a directory, and you've been retrying the same command quite often, you should probably use rsync, which first checks if files differ (with md5 checksums) before transferring them. You can also resume big file transfers with the `--partial` option.

```
rsync -avz --partial --progress --rsh=ssh Files-from-Server-A [...] user@B:/tmp/
```

Comment: thanks for reminding of rysnc I really forgot about using rsync.

Answer (score 5):

General advice is to use terminal multiplexer (e.g. `tmux` or `screen`) and run the copy inside, since that gives one much flexibility. You can detach/reattach as necessary to check how the operation proceeds.

These programs create "virtual" (headless) terminals which are displayed on/take input from  a "real" terminal (linux console, X terminal emulators, ssh connection...). As the virtual terminal is not affected by interruptions in the real terminals (the terminal multiplexer just stops displaying output when it detects the IO device being closed and keeps storing output into it's internal buffer), the applications running inside are shielded from SIGHUP. As a bonus, they usually offer at least some basic text-mod windowing capabilities.

I'm not sure about [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) (which is actively developed), but [GNU `screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) should be included in standard RHEL repository.

Comment: Could you please provide more detail as im not aware of this feature. It will be awesome if any one of these which you mentioned works with case I mentioned above.

Comment: @UmairMustafa it turned out to be a bit longer, so I've updated the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`lftp` (a general purpose terminal file transfer program) supports `sftp` (not `scp`, but if you have `scp`, you have `ssh` and most likely it supports `sftp` as well), and it can put transfers in background, automatically reconnect and resume the transfer (after a customisable delay) upon failure and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use `rsync`? Such a big transfer is sure to break somewhere, and I'm not sure the mechanisms proposed are able to continue from where it broke off.